# How to grant permission to native excutable

Tags: java, android, c++, native

I created a C++ Native executable and I succesfully start it with adb and rooted Android.
Now I would like to launch my executable  from Android Service. Therfore I am using  :
    runtime.exec ("/sdcard/test/myApp
   /sdcard/test/conf.txt")

I also added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  permissions in Manifest file and allowed permission  in runtime.
My executable start but cannot read argument file "conf.txt"
How do I add or transfer permission to acess files and so on?

Comment: Are you sure that path is valid?

Comment: Yes the path is valid. Also when I use the same file and the same application in rooted emulator it works in no root device fopen () or access () returns Null value